# Check duplicates in nvarchar column of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables: `Import` and `ImportItem`. One `Import` has multiple `ImportItem`. One `ImportItem` has one `Import`.

In my `ImportItem` I have a column `CountryIDs`. It's an `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. It is a string of IDs with `;` as delimiter so for example: `3; 4; 5;...`

I need to determine duplicates, actually if I run on a duplicate I need to raise some error. So `3; 4; 3;` ... 3 is duplicate.

I have a split function (I did not write that function, I was told to use it) that splits a string (`nvarchar`) and returns a table with columns `ItemNo` and `Item` (from previous example it would return 1 for `ItemNo` and 3 for `Item`, 2 for `ItemNo` and 4 for `Item`.

I need to write a procedure. My question is, how can I iterate through that column of CountryIDs for given `ImportItem` ID and split it and check for duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` to get the list of items, something like this:

```
select ii.itemno, s.c, count(*) as cnt
from importitem ii apply
     dbo.split(ii.countryids) as s(c)
group by ii.itemno, s.c
having count(*) > 1;
```

Once you have the list, you can decide how to process it in the stored procedure.